# Override 'plugindirs' configuration property before running "dita install"?

Tags: dita-ot

how do I override the `plugindirs` property on/before running `dita install` without having to modify the `configuration.properties` file in-place in the DITA-OT distribution folder?

I tried

```
dita install --propertyfile=/my/custom/configuration.properties
dita install -Dplugindirs=my/custom/plugins
```

none of which worked resp. gave errors about unsupported options.

I really want to keep my configuration property customizations out of the DITA-OT distribution folder, as otherwise, any DITA-OT distribution update (replacing the current distribution folder and hence the contained `configuration.properties` file) will inevitably overwrite them.

What is the proper DITA-OT way of overriding the `plugindirs` default value without having to edit the `configuration.properties` file in-place, esp. for use in `dita install` command?

Thank you,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the DITA OT code and in the DITA OT docs:
https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/parameters/configuration-properties-file.html
there is no current way to load the configuration.properties from another location. I guess your script could copy a configuration.properties over the one in the DITA OT before running the DITA OT.
I found this very recent work being done on the DITA OT to allow for a properties file to exist in the user home folder, I added a link to your question there to see if it could also cover this aspect:
https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/pull/4217#issuecomment-1613708823